# BEM CSS Inheritance?

Tags: css, bem

I am working on a large scale website. We are considering to write CSS in BEM style, but not sure if this is actually a good practice. CSS is all about inheritance, but I don't see that in BEM. For example:

```
.toolbar {
  &-btn {}  
}
```

VS

```
.toolbar {
  .btn {}
}
```

The .btn in 2nd example can inherit from global .btn class, but .toolbar-btn class will not inherit those default properties. So you end up writing a lot repeatitive properties. Why people say BEM is reusable at all if it doesn't inherit properties?
Edit: We are trying to avoid using extend feature as much as possible.

Comment: Hi, could you please elaborate on why you really want to avoid "extend" ? Will placeholders  be a  better choice ?

Comment: placeholder is definitely better than extend from a regular class, because extend can easily create bloat css without your notice. SCSS's extend is especially dangers because it also extends child classes when you don't want it.

Comment: If I understand BEM correctly you basically don't use CSS inheritance. One of their points is exactly that CSS inheritance is very nice but it easily transforms your project CSS into an unmanageable mess where it's not immediate checking the HTML where can a class be used and if requires some parent elements or not. Check https://www.phase2technology.com/blog/used-and-abused-css-inheritance-and-our-misuse-of-the-cascade/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to define `.btn` as a global class, you should use it as a modifier (for variations)

```
 .btn.btn--primary

 // OR
 .my-cool-btn.btn--primary.btn--red
```

Here is the Google's approach for the new "Material Design Lite" framework

```
 .mdl-layout__container  //Parent element

 --- .mdl-layout  //Block

 ------ .mdl-layout__header   //element

 ------ .mdl-layout__content  //element
```

And some modifiers on the `.mdl-layout__header` element

```
// Local modifiers
.mdl-layout__header-row
.mdl-layout__header--scroll


// Global modifiers
.demo-header 
.is-casting-shadow
.mdl-color--grey-100
.mdl-color-text--grey-800
```

I highly suggest you take a look at their [repository](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/tree/master/src)  and this [template example](http://www.getmdl.io/templates/text-only/index.html)

Comment: It doesn't seem to answer my question. Your local modifiers such as .mdl-layout__header-row
.mdl-layout__header--scroll are not inherit from global .row and scroll class. Are you saying you have to rewrite row  property for local modifier?

Comment: nvm, I think i know what you are saying. Combining other .btn-modifier would add that inheritance to local module or module modifiers. Thanks

Comment: So we should use 'inheritance' of rules in the HTML markup side only ? Combining several rules, something like <div class="toolbar" >+<div class="btn btn--toolbar"> or something where "btn--toolbar" would be defined specifically for this toolbar but not "btn"..? Though we would not see the 'btn' class only by looking at the css of the component but we would know it exists because of the "--modifier" suffix ??

Comment: No, I think you missed the point. your btn--toolbar should not be a class coupled with toolbar. Anything coupled with toolbar should be .toolbar-element. Generic classes like btn or btn-primary should be global accessible.